# StreamWriter.Flush(); won't flush

Tags: c#, java, unity-game-engine, flush

i am trying to link a Unity game to a Java server using C#

when the Java server up the only way i can send data is by closing the StreamWriter (OUT.Close();) which actually closes the connection too. so i can only send data onces. or, every time i want to send a message, i have to reconnect to the server again.

when i just use Flush(), the data will not be send to the server.
Code:

```
NetworkStream STREAM = connection.GetStream();
StreamWriter OUT = new StreamWriter(STREAM);
OUT.Write(text);
OUT.Flush()
```

this is my reading code:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
String inputstring = input.readLine();
```

Comment: I suspect the bug is in your reading code, not in your writing code. A wild guess is that you don't treat the stream you're reading as a stream, and expect packets.

Comment: this is my reading code BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
      String inputstring = input.readLine();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write text without a line separator with `Write` and read with `ReadLine`, so this doesn't match up. In the absence of line separators, `ReadLine` reads to the end of the stream, which explains why you need to close the stream. Replace `Write` with `WriteLine`.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!! :D! this really frustrated me because no matter how i approached the problem, it never seemed to go away. i can finally move on! :D